# Combine two numbers into one and extract them back

Tags: integers, compression

I have two numbers(A,B), I want to combine the numbers into one(C)

The constraints are

1. A's range = 0 to 3 (4 values)
2. B's range = 0 to 900 (900 values)
3. C must have a maximum of 3 digits only.

Example:

Input: A=2, B=635

Calculate C, lets say C = 2 + 635 = 637 (only 3 digits)

Given C = 637, Extract A = 2 & B = 635.

===============

A's range is fixed at 4.

B's range can be reduced from 900, but cannot go below 500.

C MUST be 3 digits only

Comment: How about $C = 1000A + B$ ? When you know $A<4$ and $B<1000$, you can take $B= C \mod{1000}$ and $A  = C/1000$ (integer division)

Comment: It works, but in this case, number of digits in C goes to 4.

Answer (score 3):

If $C$ has a maximum of $3$ digits, then it's impossible. There are only $1000$ possibilities ($1999$ if it can be negative), but it would need to cover $4\cdot 900=3600$ different combinations of $A$ and $B$. There just isn't room.

If you allow four digits, then $C=1000A+B$ works.

Comment: Thank you Arthur, Will it be possible if i reduce B's range to 512?

Comment: Thank you Arthur for the confirmation. I have a hard limit of 3 digits..Looks like its not possible.

Comment: @Anand I misread $A$. It has 4 possibilities, not 3. So it's $900\cdot4$ or $512\cdot 4$. So even negative $C$ isn't enough.

Comment: Thank you Arthur :-(